# I have another method about getting the list of checkbox

Tags: python, django

A method that is recommended by most of people:

```
files_form_checked_chkbox = request.POST.getlist("file_of_chkbox")
for every_file in files_form_checked_chkbox:
    #do somethig
```

This is B method that I find:

```
keys = request.POST.keys()
for key in keys:
    if key != "csrfmiddlewaretoken":
        #do somethig
```

This is my template:

```
<p>List</p>
<form action="..." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for key in keys %}
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="file_of_chkbox" value="{{key}}">
        <a href="..." >{{key}}</a>
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete files" />
</form>
```

Both methods can do same thing.

I see. It's sure that A is better than B and A is explained many time.
I use request

But I want to understand why B is't recommended with reson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is not doing the same thing as A.

While looping over `request.POST.keys()` you are doing a lot of extra work by getting the POST parameters you don't even need.

First option is doing exactly what you need to do - get the list of checkbox values. And it is readable.

Comment: If both method compare performance and readability, it's sure that A is better than B. Do you have any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the B method, this one implements the "Synchronizer token pattern" to prevent Cross-site request forgery vulnerability

Learn more about CSRF:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Do you have a specific example with django?